# Jquery - How do I make ifModified:true work in .ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple script where an Ajax request is made every 2 seconds. If the data fetched from a php page called "ext" is different from the last data acquired, the code runs a function: in order to do this I use the ifModified:true setting on the ajax request, but it doesn't work.

This is the code I am using

```
$(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(repeat,2000);

function repeat(){
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "ext.php",
  ifModified: true,
  success:function(data) {
$('.photo').fadeOut(5000).delay(1000).css('background-image', 'url(' + data + ')' ).fadeIn(5000);
}
});
}

});
```

and this is the code found in the "ext.php": its aim is to simply output the path to the last added jpg into a directory.

```
<?php
$array = glob("images/{*.jpg,*.JPG}", GLOB_BRACE);
$ultimo = end($array);
?>
<?php echo $ultimo; ?>
```

At the present time the script sets an image, whose path is found in ext.php, as the background of the div with class ".photo" with a fadeOut and a fadeIn. My idea is that when the path is the same as the previous used, the image shouldn't repeat the fadeOut and fadeIn but just stay still until a new path is provided.

What am I missing?

Comment: ext.php may not be setting the last-modified time in its header. (Source for that file would probably help to debug.)

Comment: I added the php code to the question

Answer (score 6):

When an Ajax request is completed successfully, the `success` callback is invoked with 3 arguments:

1. `data` the data returned
2. `status` text status string with value `"success"`
3. `jqXHR` the jQuery XMLHttpRequest object returned (this argument is irrelevant for this problem so I omitted further info. Read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR))

When you set the property `ifModified: true` on an Ajax request, after a second request with the same data on the same URL the `success` callback is invoked with 3 arguments:

1. `data` the data returned has value `undefined`
2. `status` text status string with value `"notmodified"`
3. `jqXHR` the jQuery XMLHttpRequest object returned (this argument is irrelevant for this problem so I omitted further info. Read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR))

In the success callback you have to check the `status` value if `status === "success"` then proceed, if status equals `"notmodified"` you don't do anything.

```
    success: function(data, status) {
        if (status === "success") {
            // New data received, do what you want
        } else {
            // if not modified data is undefined 
        }
    }
```

**Bonus:** you can get the old data from cache if `status === "notmodified"` via `jqXHR.responseText`. If your `dataType` is not text (ie.  JSON, JSONP, script, etc.), you must first convert the string `jqXHR.responseText` to your desired dataType.

Comment: What if I always want to process the 'content'?  Is there a way to get the 'cached' data?